# Pytest plugin ignoring hooks for test run

Tags: python, plugins, pytest, hook

I am trying to add a plugin to eavesdrop on my pytest runs. from what I can find in code samples and documentation, this "should" work (emphasis on should)

```
"""
    to test scripted pytest control
"""
import sys

import pytest


class MyPytestPlugin:
    """
    Hooks to get info from pytest
    """

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

    # pylint: disable=unused-argument
    def pytest_collection_modifyitems(self, config, items):
        print("collection done.")

    def pytest_sessionstart(self, session):
        print("*" * 10)
        print("session started", session)
        print("*" * 10)

    def pytest_sessionfinish(self, session, exitstatus):
        print("-" * 10)
        print("session finished", session)

    def pytest_runtest_logstart(self, nodeid, location):
        print("<<<<< log start >>>>>>", nodeid)

    def pytest_runtest_logfinish(self, nodeid, location):
        print("<<<<< log finish >>>>>>", nodeid)

    def pytest_runtest_protocol(self, item, nextitem):
        print("<<<<< protocol >>>>>>")

    def pytest_collectreport(self, report):
        print("<<<<< collect report >>>>>>")

    def pytest_report_teststatus(self, report):
        print("<<<<< test status >>>>>>")

    def pytest_runtest_setup(self, item):
        print("<<<<< setup >>>>>>")

    def pytest_runtest_call(self, item):
        print("<<<<< runtest call >>>>>>")

    def pytest_runtest_teardown(self, item):
        print("<<<<< runtest teardown >>>>>>")


my_plugin = MyPytestPlugin()
sys.exit(
    pytest.main(
        ["-s", "sample_test.py"],
        plugins=[my_plugin],
    )
)
```

however, when I run this, only the session (start/finish) and the log (start/finish) print their message. nothing else (for example, the runtest setup, call, teardown etc.) seems to be called. has anyone seen this before?

here is the output

```
python sample_test_runner.py 
Test session starts (platform: linux, Python 3.9.6, pytest 7.2.0, pytest-sugar 0.9.5)
cachedir: .pytest_cache
metadata: {'Python': '3.9.6', 'Platform': 'Linux-5.10.124-linuxkit-x86_64-with-glibc2.28', 'Packages': {'pytest': '7.2.0', 'py': '1.11.0', 'pluggy': '1.0.0'}, 'Plugins': {'cov': '4.0.0', 'xdist': '3.0.2', 'metadata': '2.0.2', 'aiohttp': '0.3.0', 'asyncio': '0.16.0', 'html': '3.1.1', 'sugar': '0.9.5', 'email': '0.3', 'forked': '1.4.0', 'timeout': '2.1.0'}}
rootdir: /src/*******, configfile: tox.ini
plugins: cov-4.0.0, xdist-3.0.2, metadata-2.0.2, aiohttp-0.3.0, asyncio-0.16.0, html-3.1.1, sugar-0.9.5, email-0.3, forked-1.4.0, timeout-2.1.0
timeout: 7200.0s
timeout method: signal
timeout func_only: False
**********
session started <Session xxxxxxxx exitstatus=<ExitCode.OK: 0> testsfailed=0 testscollected=0>
**********
[gw0] Python 3.9.6 (default, Aug 17 2021, 02:38:04)  -- [GCC 8.3.0]
[gw1] Python 3.9.6 (default, Aug 17 2021, 02:38:04)  -- [GCC 8.3.0]
[gw2] Python 3.9.6 (default, Aug 17 2021, 02:38:04)  -- [GCC 8.3.0]
gw0 [5] / gw1 [5] / gw2 [5]
scheduling tests via LoadScheduling
<<<<< log start >>>>>> sample_test.py::test_addon[t1]
<<<<< log start >>>>>> sample_test.py::test_addon[t2]
<<<<< log start >>>>>> sample_test.py::test_addon[t3]


[gw0] PASSED sample_test.py 
 sample_test.py::test_addon[t2] ✓                                                                                                                                                                                            20% ██        
[gw1] PASSED sample_test.py                                                                                                                                                                                                               
<<<<< log finish >>>>>> sample_test.py::test_addon[t2]
 sample_test.py::test_addon[t1] ✓                                                                                                                                                                                            60% ██████    

 sample_test.py::test_addon[t3] ✓                                                                                                                                                                                            40% ████      
[gw2] PASSED sample_test.py                                                                                                                                                                                                               
<<<<< log finish >>>>>> sample_test.py::test_addon[t3]
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
<<<<< log finish >>>>>> sample_test.py::test_addon[t1]
<<<<< log start >>>>>> sample_test.py::test_addon[t4]

 sample_test.py::test_addon[t5] ✓                                                                                                                                                                                            80% ████████  
[gw1] PASSED sample_test.py                                                                                                                                                                                                               
<<<<< log finish >>>>>> sample_test.py::test_addon[t5]

 sample_test.py::test_addon[t4] ✓                                                                                                                                                                                           100% ██████████
[gw0] PASSED sample_test.py                                                                                                                                                                                                               
<<<<< log finish >>>>>> sample_test.py::test_addon[t4]

----------
session finished <Session xxxxxxxxx exitstatus=0 testsfailed=0 testscollected=5> 0 0 5



Results (0.70s):
       5 passed
```

for the curious, here is my test file:

```
import pytest


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "a,b,expected",
    [
        pytest.param(1, 1, 2, id="t1"),
        pytest.param(2, 2, 4, id="t2"),
        pytest.param(2, 1, 3, id="t3"),
        pytest.param(2, 3, 5, id="t4"),
        pytest.param(3, 4, 7, id="t5"),
    ],
)
def test_addon(a, b, expected):
    print(f"{a}, {b}, {expected}")
    assert a + b == expected
```

**Update**:
Thanks to @Teejay, it is true that in cases like these we should wrap the hook. however, even if we change all the above hooks to generators like below, we still won't get any output except from session and log start and finish hooks:

```
 @pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
    def pytest_runtest_protocol(self, item, nextitem):
        print("<<<<< protocol >>>>>>")
        outcome = yield
        # outcome.excinfo may be None or a (cls, val, tb) tuple
        print(outcome.get_result())
```

neither will anything change if these methods were static:

```
 @pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
 @staticmethod
 def pytest_runtest_protocol(item, nextitem):
        print("<<<<< protocol >>>>>>")
        outcome = yield
        # outcome.excinfo may be None or a (cls, val, tb) tuple
        print(outcome.get_result())
```

Comment: Without looking into this too thoroughly, I would assume it's because you re-defined the functions when you actually want/intended to wrap them. I recommend reading https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/writing_hook_functions.html#hookwrapper-executing-around-other-hooks

Comment: you are right, I just removed them to have a smaller code sample. even if I turn them all to generators like below, the result would be the same. (session and log are the only ones who work.

` @pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)

    def pytest_runtest_protocol(self, item, nextitem):

        print("<<<<< protocol >>>>>>")

        outcome = yield

      
        print(outcome.get_result())
`